# material chips with texts

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material

I want to combine chips with normal text input. Here https://material.angular.io/components/chips/overview#chip-input shows that you can insert chips inside input field. But I want to combine them with standard text.

Below image shows What I want to see

[image: What I want to see]

Basically I want "rich text editor" like input. You can put chips and text freely.

Comment: what have you tried? where are you stuck? It'll be easier to help if you share a stackblitz of where you're stuck

Comment: Do you mean appear 4 chips as maximum?

Comment: @AbdelrhmanArnos no. I want a "rich text editor" like input. I want to combine (put them side by side) chips and normal text

Comment: Did you ever come up with a solution?

Comment: @RichardMedeiros No. I think the only solution could be making your own angular component. Let me know if you find.

Answer (score 0):

As I understood you want to combine chip with normal text. try this

in HTML file

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-chip-list #chipList>
        <mat-chip>{{data.chipText}}</mat-chip>{{data.noramlText}}
  </mat-chip-list>
</mat-form-field>
```

in Typescript file

```
export class AppComponent {

  data = {chipText: 'Chip 1', noramlText:'1'};

}
```

Comment: That's a good answer but does not really achieve what I want. I want something like a rich text editor. I want to freely put text and chip as I wanted. I think I need to build my own module for this

Comment: Have you found any solution for your scenario? @canbax

Comment: no. I think you should write your own angular component. Maybe somebody already did it